# Making cached script files to refresh on client machines

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-7, .net-4.0

We have faced a problem on one of our production sites. JavaScript file was updated for a page and uploaded to IIS. We directly include file using

```
<script src="PATH_TO_SCRIPT" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

We started receiving complaints from clients that the page is broken. It was happening as the JS file was cached on client machines and was not refreshed from server.

How can we avoid this kind of scenarios without changing javascript file name in future?

ASP.Net bundling and minification might be helpful. But there are lot of pages and site is quite legacy. Almost all the pages have some heavy logic written in associated js file.

The site is running .Net 4.0 and IIS 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundling and minification is indeed the correct way to handle this because it will take care of properly appending the correct version number to the url when rendering the script.

But if this is a legacy site and for some reasons you cannot use bundling, one possibility would be to write a server side helper that will generate the script tag and calculate a checksum of the file and append the proper query string parameter:

```
public static class ScriptExtensions
{
    public static string Script(this Page page, string relativeUrl)
    {
        var path = page.Server.MapPath(relativeUrl);
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            return string.Format(
                "<script type=\"type/javascript\" src=\"{0}?v={1}\"></script>",
                page.ResolveUrl(relativeUrl),
                Hash(path)
            );
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    private static string Hash(string file)
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
        using (var bs = new BufferedStream(stream))
        {
            using (var sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(bs);
                var result = new StringBuilder(2 * hash.Length);
                foreach (byte b in hash)
                {
                    result.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
                }
                return result.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then inside your WebForm use the helper to include your scripts:

```
<%= this.Script("~/scripts/example.js") %>
```

which will emit the following markup:

```
<script type="type/javascript" src="/scripts/example.js?v=3C222D8DFA2A02A02E9A585EA6FE0D95673E8B4A"></script>
```

Now when you change the contents of the script file, its SHA1 checksum will be different and a different version query string parameter will be generated and appended busting all client side cache.

Comment: I had this kind of scheme in mind like using custom server side control to include scripts in page but only thing that stopped was that how will this effect the overall render time for the page? Well I know I should have implemented and experimented with this before asking the question. Is it possible to cache it so that it is not re-calculated every-time?

Comment: Sure, you could look at the last modified date of the javascript file and decide whether you want to recalculate the hash or not. You might have cached the last modification date and decide based on that information. Basically it's what the bundling do in ASP.NET. Really if you can not reinvent the wheel, just use it.

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration. I stitched up something over bundling infrastructure.

Comment: In this solution, will the hash be calculated each time the view is rendered? Won't this be affecting performance severely?

Comment: @Bertvan, yes in this example the hash will be calculated on each request and yes it might have negative performance hit. But I never said that this is a production ready code that you can just copy-paste into your application. I just illustrated the concept. It is more than obvious that if you want to integrate this in a production system you will have to consider caching the hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from Darin's solution I decided to go with Bundling and Minification to get the benefits of all the goodies it has to offer, I came up with the following solution. Add a static class with Extension method for Page type:

```
public static class ScriptExtensions
{
    public static string Script(this Page page, string relativeUrl)
    {
        var path = page.Server.MapPath(relativeUrl);
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            return BundlesConfig.AddPageScript(relativeUrl);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The `BundlesConfig` class contians methods to generate bundle for js file and add to Bundles:

```
public class BundlesConfig
{
    private static readonly ICollection<string> addedScripts 
                                                     = new HashSet<string>();
    private static readonly string bundleTemplate = "~/bundles/scripts/{0}";

    internal static string AddPageScript(string relativeUrl)
    {            
            var fileName = CleanFileName(relativeUrl);
            var bundleName = string.Format(bundleTemplate, fileName);

            if(!addedScripts.Contains(fileName))
            {
                var bundle = new ScriptBundle(bundleName);
                bundle.Include(relativeUrl);
                addedScripts.Add(fileName);
                BundleTable.Bundles.Add(bundle);
            }
      return System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(bundleName).ToHtmlString();
    }

    private static string CleanFileName(string url)
    {
        if (url.Contains("/"))
        {
            return url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).Replace('.', '_')
                          .Replace("-", "__");
        }

        return url.Replace('.', '_').Replace("-", "__");
    }
}
```

Now on pages instead of standard `script` tag:

```
<scrip type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-min.js"></script>
```

we use:

```
<%= this.Script("~/Scripts/jquery-min.js") %>
```

The method spits following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/scripts/jquery__min_js?v=...."></script>
```